# Flat JSON from API to SQL in Azure

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use ADF Web Activity as source in order to update a SQL table.
The problem with the output I get from the API is that it is not on a nested format and therefore not possible to use the Foreach activity I normally use.

This is the error message I get Error code;

```
InvalidTemplate
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
The expression 'activity('NordpoolKRSNO2').output.data' cannot be evaluated because property 'data' doesn't exist, available properties are '2021-02-04T00:00:00+01:00, 2021-02-04T01:00:00+01:00, 2021-02-04T02:00:00+01:00, 2021-02-04T03:00:00+01:00, 2021-02-04T04:00:00+01:00, 2021-02-04T05:00:00+01:00, 2021-02-04T06:00:00+01:00, 2021-
```

And this is the output from the web acitivty.

```
{
    "2021-02-04T00:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.3623,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-03T23:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T01:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.3572,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T00:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T01:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T02:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.3518,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T01:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T02:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T03:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.3583,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T02:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T03:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T04:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.3832,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T03:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T04:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T05:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.4098,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T04:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T05:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T06:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.5009,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T05:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T06:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T07:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.5924,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T06:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T07:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T08:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.6136,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T07:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T08:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T09:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.5981,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T08:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T09:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T10:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.5695,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T09:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T10:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T11:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.585,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T10:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T11:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T12:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.5814,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T11:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T12:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T13:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.5773,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T12:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T13:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T14:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.5863,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T13:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T14:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T15:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.6032,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T14:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T15:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T16:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.616,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T15:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T16:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T17:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.7412,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T16:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T18:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.7412,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T17:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T18:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T19:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.6998,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T18:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T19:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T20:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.6156,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T19:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T20:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T21:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.562,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T20:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T21:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T22:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.5417,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T21:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T22:00:00Z"
    },
    "2021-02-04T23:00:00+01:00": {
        "NOK_per_kWh": 0.4791,
        "valid_from": "2021-02-04T22:00:00Z",
        "valid_to": "2021-02-04T23:00:00Z"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t undertand you, if you format the json, its a list

```
{
   "2021-02-04T00:00:00+01:00": ...,
   "2021-02-04T00:00:00+01:00": ...
}
```

Why u dont map the API response to serialize to List and iterate through the list?

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to do. Though, when i use the ForEAch activity in ADF it fails because it needs a "startingpoint" - typically @activity('NordpoolKRSNO2').output